# Group Messaging Fetch Associative Array from mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

My Group messaging system uses an array to control numbers and names

```
$people = array(
    "+14031234567" => "Test Black Berry",
    "+14038999999" => "Test Android",
    "+14036519999" => "Test iPhone",
);
```

I have attempted to use php to get this information from a mysql db

```
<?php
include("config.php");
$connect = new mysqli("$dbhost","$dbuser","$dbpass","$dbname")
or die (mysqli_error());

$people=$connect->query("SELECT phone, name FROM contacts");
        while($row=$people->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        echo 
        $row ['phone']." => ".$row['name'].","; 
        }
?>
```

which gives me the result

```
   +14037777777 => Test Black Berry,
   +14038888888 => Test Android,
   +14039999999 => Test iPhone,
```

Close but not quite all the way.  What am I missing.  Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Close as in? I can`t see a difference...

Comment: It does not have the comments " "  and when I try to use $people variable in my Group Messaging App it does not function.  The $people = array(); works fine but not the php code snippit

Comment: in the foreach replace with `$array[$row ['phone']] = $row['name'];`
Declare `$array = array();` outside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
This the final code that works in my Message App 

<?php
include("../../lib/config.php");
$conn=mysqli_connect("$dbhost","$dbuser","$dbpass","$dbname")
or die (mysqli_error());
$query = "SELECT phone, name FROM grouplist";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$people = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $people[$row['phone']] = $row['name'];
}   
?>
```